GPG simple chain of trust
I'm generating gpg keys, and trying to create chain of trusts. In this example everything happens in same directory. But it is not the goal. The chain trust will be :
Jhon -> James -> Peter
#!/usr/bin/bash

rm -rf /dev/shm/*_gpg && export GNUPGHOME=$(mktemp -d -p /dev/shm --suffix _gpg) && chmod 0700 ${GNUPGHOME}

# Generate JHON_KEY
cat > generation.conf << EOF
Key-Type: RSA
Key-Length: 1024
Key-Usage: cert
Name-Real: Jhon jhon
Name-Email: jhon@gmail.com
Name-Comment: JHON_KEY
Expire-Date: 0
%no-protection
%commit
EOF

gpg -q --batch --generate-key ./generation.conf
echo ----------------------
gpg -q --armor --export JHON_KEY > jhon.pub.asc
gpg -q --armor --export-secret-keys JHON_KEY > jhon.priv.asc
gpg -q --armor --export-ownertrust > trust.db

rm -rf /dev/shm/*_gpg && export GNUPGHOME=$(mktemp -d -p /dev/shm --suffix _gpg) && chmod 0700 ${GNUPGHOME}

# Generate JAMES_KEY
cat > generation.conf << EOF
Key-Type: RSA
Key-Length: 1024
Key-Usage: cert
Name-Real: James james
Name-Email: james@gmail.com
Name-Comment: JAMES_KEY
Expire-Date: 0
%no-protection
%commit
EOF

gpg -q --batch --generate-key ./generation.conf
gpg -q --armor --export JAMES_KEY > james.pub.asc
gpg -q --armor --export-secret-keys JAMES_KEY > james.priv.asc

# Generate PETER_KEY
cat > generation.conf << EOF
Key-Type: RSA
Key-Length: 1024
Key-Usage: cert
Name-Real: Peter peter
Name-Email: peter@gmail.com
Name-Comment: PETER_KEY
Expire-Date: 0
%no-protection
%commit
EOF

gpg -q --batch --generate-key ./generation.conf
# PETER_KEY is signed by JAMES_KEY
gpg -q --batch --yes --default-key 'JAMES_KEY' --sign-key 'PETER_KEY'
gpg -q --export PETER_KEY > peter.pub.asc
gpg -q --export-secret-keys PETER_KEY > peter.priv.asc

rm -rf /dev/shm/*_gpg && export GNUPGHOME=$(mktemp -d -p /dev/shm --suffix _gpg) && chmod 0700 ${GNUPGHOME}
gpg -q --import jhon.priv.asc
gpg -q  --import-ownertrust trust.db
gpg -q --import james.priv.asc

# JAMES_KEY is signed by JHON_KEY
gpg -q --batch --yes --default-key 'JHON_KEY' --sign-key 'JAMES_KEY'
gpg -q --armor --export JAMES_KEY > james.pub.asc
gpg -q --armor --export-secret-keys JAMES_KEY > james.priv.asc

rm -rf /dev/shm/*_gpg && export GNUPGHOME=$(mktemp -d -p /dev/shm --suffix _gpg) && chmod 0700 ${GNUPGHOME}
gpg -q  --import  jhon.pub.asc
gpg -q  --import-ownertrust trust.db
gpg -q  --import  james.pub.asc
gpg -q  --import  peter.pub.asc
gpg --check-trustdb
gpg --list-sigs
echo '********************************************************************************************'
cat trust.db

rm -rf /dev/shm/*_gpg

This is my output:
pub   rsa1024 2024-11-18 [C]
      597DE3BFFF6E80E3DB29D07440AB65B16AAB2377
uid           [ultimate] Jhon jhon (JHON_KEY) <jhon@gmail.com>
sig 3        40AB65B16AAB2377 2024-11-18  [self-signature]

pub   rsa1024 2024-11-18 [C]
      C3DBA67CD211C7457DDEBC30BEF1A819D331DB81
uid           [  full  ] James james (JAMES_KEY) <james@gmail.com>
sig 3        BEF1A819D331DB81 2024-11-18  [self-signature]
sig          40AB65B16AAB2377 2024-11-18  Jhon jhon (JHON_KEY) <jhon@gmail.com>

pub   rsa1024 2024-11-18 [C]
      1EF8105B44C70350AC863D5C380FBC0B0688C646
uid           [  undef ] Peter peter (PETER_KEY) <peter@gmail.com>
sig 3        380FBC0B0688C646 2024-11-18  [self-signature]
sig          BEF1A819D331DB81 2024-11-18  James james (JAMES_KEY) <james@gmail.com>

********************************************************************************************
# List of assigned trustvalues, created Mon Nov 18 16:58:04 2024 CET
# (Use "gpg --import-ownertrust" to restore them)
597DE3BFFF6E80E3DB29D07440AB65B16AAB2377:6:



Why Peter is trusted with undef level ? It is signed by James ! As you can see James is marked as fully trusted only because it is signed by Jhon (James is not in trustdb).
Thanks.

The [ foo ] indicator doesn't show owner trust – it shows key validity. Those are often confused (sometimes even within GnuPG's own docs), but are not the same concept:

validity indicates the quality of the key itself, i.e. whether it has received enough signatures by other trusted keys,

whereas trust indicates whether that key – or rather the key's owner – may give validity to other keys by signing them (and comes from its own validity plus the trustdb).


A key must already be valid before it can be given trust to validate others – but that's only one of the requirements; a valid key does not automatically become a trusted key.
So in this case, [  full  ] means that James's key is valid (as in, confirmed that it indeed belongs to James) after it has been signed by your ultimately-trusted key, but the listing says nothing about the trust it has to give validity any further (i.e. whether this is a Gullible James or a Cypherpunk James). Therefore, even though Peter's key is signed by James, that signature currently has zero weight in the WoT model.
(In other words, trust decays in the WoT model – it is not infinitely transitive, meaning that you can safely sign James's key without risking that they would unknowingly lead to a chain James→Peter→C→D→E→F→G... where person G happens to be someone who signs any random key key without checking anything.)
Validity of a key is calculated automatically from the signatures it has received (and from trust of all signers), whereas trust isn't assigned to a key but rather to the key's owner – hence "ownertrust" in the gpg command line – and relies on human judgment, so it needs to be set manually through the trustdb.
This is usually done using gpg --update-trustdb which interactively asks you whether you trust the owner of each [fully valid] key to validate other keys. If you choose "I trust James fully", then one signature from James will be enough to validate Peter's key, whereas marginal trust only gives 1/3rd of 'validity' – i.e. three "marginally trusted" people need to sign a key for it to be valid in your point of view.
Trust of specific keys can also be changed using gpg --edit-key James trust. You can of course automate it via gpg --import-ownertrust, where 5 gives full trust and 4 gives marginal trust.
Further explained in:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41208/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-this-gpg-output-regarding-trust

